# Hypothesis testing - Difference proportions: Pooled vs Unpooled for one-tailed tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, pooling, one-tailed-test

Problem 2 of the Stattrek tutorial (https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx?Tutorial=AP) tries to determine whether a drug is more effective for women than for men. They use pooled variance as a part of their one-tailed test. I understand that using pooled variance makes sense in two-tailed tests where the null hypothesis often assumes that the two groups have been sampled from the same population (or two populations with same variance). But in the case of one-tailed tests, where the null hypothesis assumes that the corresponding populations are different (and hence their variances too), wouldn't using unpooled variance be more appropriate?

Comment: You seem to have confused the null with the *alternative* hypothesis, because the null is the same in both situations: namely, that the groups are sampled from the same population.

Comment: Thanks, whuber. But, the null hypothesis of the problem is P1 >= P2. So, wouldn't this imply that the null assumes that the groups are sampled from different populations?

Comment: This concerns the distinction between a *simple* and a *composite* hypothesis: you describe the latter. It turns out in this case that the testing is performed as if the null hypothesis were $p_1=p_2,$ because that's the worst case for the rate of false positives.  What distinguishes the two tests you describe therefore are the *alternative* hypotheses: $p_1\ne p_2$ for the two-tailed test and $p_1\lt p_2$ for the one-tailed test.